# Find and Where confusion in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, associations

I have an association of has_many :through with tags, taggings and categories

Tags

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :categories, through: :taggings
```

Taggings

```
belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :category
```

Categories

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :categories, through: :taggings
```

When I try to query

```
tag = Tag.where("name LIKE ?", "#{query}")
tag.categories
```

there's an error:

```
Undefined categories
```

I don't know what the difference when you use find and where because when I used find it works fine. Can you give me the idea why?

Answer (score 1):

`where` returns an array that contains result. `find` on the other hand returns an object. Try:

```
tag = Tag.where("name LIKE ?", "#{query}")
tag.first.categories
```

Comment: Or better: `Tag.find_by('name like ?', query).categories` (assuming Rails4 of course and you only want one `Tag`).

Comment: yes that will work, but OP seemed to ask why `where` didn't work. So it tried to answer that part.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first record it's simpler and more elegant to use

```rb
Tag.find_by_name(query).categories
```

Comment: Why are you doing `"#{query}"`? That seems like a convoluted way of saying `query`. Also, `find_by(:name => query)` would be better than `find_by_name` since `find_by_name` is deprecated in Rails4. Furthermore, the OP is using a LIKE query, you're not.

Comment: You're right on the first point, was just a careless copy of op's code. Will edit. I checked and find_by helpers are not deprecated in rails 4. Some other finders are. https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Right, I thought they deprecated all the `find_by_*` methods too, wishful thinking perhaps. You're still not using a LIKE query though.

Answer (score 0):

Find return an object and where clause returns the array of objects when you need to find one record by where clause then you should use:

```
tag = Tag.where("name LIKE ?", "#{query}").first
categories = tag.categories if tag
```